# How to get plaintext github actions secrets using github api

Tags: node.js, github-actions, github-api

I need to get the plaintext value for some 70+ secrets in my github organisation.

There is an endoint to get the list of secret names which i am currently using.

```
  let secretsData = await octokit.request("GET /orgs/{org}/actions/secrets", {
    org: process.env.org,
  });
```

This gives back to me a list of action/secret keys, i need the  plaintext value for each of these keys.

**usecase:**

I am migrating from github actions secrets to aws secret manager. So i need a nice way to get the keys/plaintext

Comment: It's possible to do it, but I don't think this is how you should proceed, as it would be a hack / security vulnerability. Shouldn't it be aligned with the org admins, letting them transfer those secrets (they have access to, and you don't) to the AWS secret manager instead?

Comment: Better workflow would be to use Github action which can use the value of existing secrets and POST to your new secret manager.

Comment: it's a one time thing i need to do and was hoping the api would allow me to get the plaintext value or get the value from some other means within github itself.

I am the org admin, we stored secrets in github actions but didint really think about also having them stored as plaintext somewhere else. Just assumed there would be a way via the api to get the plaintext version